# customize flash from client side

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

Is there any way to customize flash from client side ? for exemple using a browser's addon allow typing actionscript . is it possible (or any suggestion another)? look like greasemonkey (addon firefox ) it can be customize web page display using javascript and jquery

i'm playing a web game type MMORPG, traning charater's level is so hard and take time, i need an automatic programme  to do this.
thanks for reading !

Comment: Have a look also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387490/creating-a-flash-game-bot which is about making a bot.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to do. Flash files (SWF) are downloaded, and no add-ins or plugins exist that I know of to script additional actions on top (as you do with greesemonkey).

I can think of the following options:

1. Downloading the SWF (or getting from temporary internet values) and decompiling the flash. Then inserting your malicious code / reverse engineering, recompiling, and then attempt to run the SWF file directly off your computer.
2. Using a program to directly access and modify the in game variables within the memory in order to hack it.
3. Using some sort of automation application to script specific moves similar to those WOW bots.
4. Performing packet sniffing and possibly decryption in order to reverse engineer the communication protocol and upload fake results.
5. Utilizing Machine vision and an algorithm to control the mouse in order make an app that plays for you - see: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games/

Comment: thanks for the answer ? i know this is a complex problem , it depends on complex of flash game. i'll try to find out logical for my case through your suggestion. thanks again.